# Robocopy automatically taking source directory as the script file directory

Tags: powershell, robocopy

**Synopsis:**

- Script file directory name -> PowerShellScripts (in Desktop in local C:...)
- Script file name -> Dbackup.ps1
- Intended source for mirroring -> D:\ (a partition on local hard disk)
- Intended destination for mirroring -> F:\D_LAPTOP_BACKUP_ ... (F: is external SSD connected via USB)

**Script:**

```
[string]$currentDirectory = Get-Location
[DateTime]$currentDateTime = Get-Date

[string]$currentTimeStamp = $currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss")
[string]$currentDayStamp = $currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

[string]$sourcePath = "D:"
write-host "Source Path: " $sourcePath

[string]$destinationDrive = "F:"
[string]$destinationFolderName = "\D_LAPTOP_BACKUP_"
[string]$destinationPath = $destinationDrive + $destinationFolderName + $currentDayStamp
write-host "Destination Path: " $destinationPath

[string]$logFile = ""
[string]$logFileExtenstion = ".txt"
$logFile = $currentDirectory + $destinationFolderName + $currentTimeStamp + $logFileExtenstion

write-host "Log File: " $logFile

[string]$defaultDirExclusionSet = '$RECYCLE.BIN "D:\System Volume Information"'
write-host "Dir Excluded: " $defaultDirExclusionSet

[string]$commandString = "Robocopy $sourcePath $destinationPath /MIR /R:3 /W:3 /DCOPY:DAT /COPY:DATSOU /TEE /LOG:$logFile /MT:32 /XD $defaultDirExclusionSet"

write-host $commandString

Invoke-Expression $commandString
```

**Issue:**

When this script is run by opening PowerShell in Admin mode from PowerShellScripts directory (which is in Desktop) it runs fine.

*However*, when I move this PowerShellScripts directory to D:\ and this script is run by opening PowerShell in Admin mode from now moved PowerShellScripts directory, the source for mirror is no more D:\ (when the robocopy expression is run by this script). **The source automatically changes to "D:\PowerShellScripts" by robocopy**. Note source is hard-coded in script and $commandString prints properly on console and shows the intended correct expression and source.

I am confused. It was scary when it happened yesterday (/MIR used) but luckily destination was kept F:\D_LAPTOP_BACKUP_2022-07-24\ by robocopy. Kindly help.

**Result Header:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 24 July 2022 11:04:51 PM
   Source : D:\PowerShellScripts\
     Dest : F:\D_LAPTOP_BACKUP_2022-07-24\

    Files : *.*
        
 Exc Dirs : D:\System Volume Information
        
  Options : *.* /TEE /S /E /COPYALL /PURGE /MIR /MT:32 /R:3 /W:3 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try: [string]$sourcePath = "D:\"

Comment: @RetiredGeek , Thanks. It works! Would be grateful if you can help me understand reason of this interesting behavior of robocopy!

Comment: Since you didn't indicate where to START on the D: drive RF assumed the current directory, i.e. where you ran the PS from. By including the \ you are indicating the root.

Comment: @RetiredGeek the code works without \ when the script is kept in the Desktop (C:). How is it working then? How is it able to understand the root then?

Comment: Because the current default is C: referencing D: takes it from the root. When you make the current default D:\PowerShellScripts that what it used when referencing as D: